# Copy Range to a new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro to copy a range of data from different parts of a worksheet and paste it to a new worksheet.  It should do this for every worksheet in the workbook with a few specified exceptions.  This is the code I have written so far:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range

'create new worksheet, name it "Budget"
Set ws = Sheets.Add
ws.Name = "Budget"
'set column titles in the new sheet
Range("A1").Value = "Period"
Range("B1").Value = "Country"
Range("C1").Value = "Product Line"
Range("D1").Value = "Currency"
Range("E1").Value = "Sales"
'search the entire UsedRange of sheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "Summary" And ws.Name <> "Template" And ws.Name <> "Data" Then
With ws.UsedRange
    Set Rng = .Find(What:="Product Line", _
                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False).Offset(1, 0).Resize(33)
        Sheets("Budget").[F1].End(xlDown).Offset(0, -3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count).Value = Rng.Value 'put values from the Find into C column of new sheet
     Set Rng = .Find(What:="201601", _
                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False).Offset(1, 0).Resize(33)
        Sheets("Budget").[F1].End(xlDown).Offset(0, -1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count).Value = Rng.Value 'put values from the Find into D column of new sheet

End With
End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

The first part seems to work fine, but when it reaches the second "Set Rng" it doesn't go any further.  I am looking to set 5 different ranges to take data from.

Comment: What does this mean: *"Set Rng" it doesn't go any further.*  Do you get an error?

Comment: A few things I'd change - what happens if 'Product Line' isn't found? Is '201601' formatted as text or a number - it won't find a number if it's formatted as text.

Comment: "Set Rng" is set range by finding a specified cell and then setting a range of cells which will eventually be pasted to the new sheet called "Budget".

Comment: "Product Line" is always found.  The format is identical of all of the worksheets that I am trying to copy data from, only the values differ. "201601" is formatted as a number. Thanks both

Comment: "object variable or with block variable not set" is the error.

Comment: Try taking the speech marks from around 201601 - `Set Rng = .Find(What:=201601,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added this as an answer as it's too long to fit in a comment.  It's not a perfect answer, but will hopefully highlight a couple of areas to look at.

- Each range reference also includes which sheet it's looking at (omitting the sheet reference tells Excel to use the currently active sheet).
- An array to populate the headings.
- SELECT CASE instead of IF
- Space to do something if the FIND's aren't found.  You say they're all the same, but that's in a perfect world and I haven't found that yet.

Sub Test()

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsBudget As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim rUsedRange As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'create new worksheet, name it "Budget"
Set wsBudget = wb.Sheets.Add
With wsBudget
    .Name = "Budget"
    .Range("A1:E1") = Array("Period", "Country", "Product Line", "Currency", "Sales")
End With

'search the entire UsedRange of sheet.
'ActiveWorkbook or ThisWorkbook?
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Summary", "Template", "Data"
            'Do Nothing
        Case Else
            Set rUsedRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), LastCell(ws))
            With rUsedRange
                Set Rng = .Find(What:="Product Line", _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                    Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(33).Copy _
                        Destination:=wsBudget.Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(, -3).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count)
                Else
                    'Do something else if Rng not found.
                End If

                Set Rng = .Find(What:=201601, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                    Rng.Offset(1).Resize(33).Copy _
                        Destination:=wsBudget.Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(, -1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count)
                Else
                    'Do something if Rng not found.
                End If

            End With
    End Select
Next ws
```

End Sub

Have included the find last cell function:

```
Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet, Optional Col As Long = 0) As Range

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    With wrkSht
        If Col = 0 Then
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        Else
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            lLastRow = .Columns(Col).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
        End If

        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I am looking into it, but I'm not sure how to use the LastCell function.  Do I just add to my module? I'm quite new to writing macros as you can see!

Comment: Yes, just add it to a module.  The line in the code above `Set rUsedRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), LastCell(ws))` sets a reference in the `ws` worksheet range A1 to the last cell.  You could also use it as:  `Set MyRange = LastCell(Thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1"))` which would return a reference to the last cell on the sheet.  Or in the Immediate window type `?LastCell(Thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1"))`.Address`

Comment: Thanks! I managed to work it out in the end. The pasting of the data to the budget sheet includes the cell format, how can I change to to paste values only? Also I need to replicate the part where i look for the range below "201601" and do the same for "201602" and so on upto "201612".  These columns are next to each other.  Do I need to do this individually or is there another way? I appreciate your time!

Comment: To PasteSpecial just the values you'll need to split the copy line into two lines.  `Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(33).Copy Destination:=wsBudget.Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(, -3).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count)` becomes `Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(33).Copy` and `wsBudget.Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(, -3).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats`

Comment: For the number values I'd add a loop - `For x = 201601 to 201612` and use `x` as your search criteria.

Comment: This is what I have so far:

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far...

Sub Test()

```
' CreateBudgetFormat Macro

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsBudget As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim rUsedRange As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'create new worksheet, name it "Budget"
Set wsBudget = wb.Sheets.Add
With wsBudget
.Name = "Budget"
.Range("A1:E1") = Array("Period", "Country", "Product Line", "Currency", "Sales")
End With

'search the entire UsedRange of sheet.
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
Select Case ws.Name
    Case "Summary", "Template", "Data"
        'Do Nothing
    Case Else

    For x = 201601 To 201612

        Set rUsedRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), LastCell(ws))
        With rUsedRange
            Set Rng = .Find(What:="Product Line", _
                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(32).Copy
                    wsBudget.Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(, -3).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            Else
                'Do something else if Rng not found.
            End If

            Set Rng = .Find(What:="Product Line", _
                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Rng.Offset(37, 0).Resize(2).Copy
                    wsBudget.Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(, -3).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            Else
                'Do something else if Rng not found.
            End If

            Set Rng = .Find(What:=x, _
                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(32).Copy
                    wsBudget.Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(, -1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            Else
                'Do something if Rng not found.
            End If

            Set Rng = .Find(What:=x, _
                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Rng.Offset(37, 0).Resize(2).Copy
                    wsBudget.Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(, -1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            Else
                'Do something if Rng not found.
            End If

            Set Rng = .Find(What:="Ship_To_Country", _
                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Rng.Offset(, 1).Copy
                    wsBudget.Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(, -4).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(34).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            Else
                'Do something if Rng not found.
            End If

            Set Rng = .Find(What:=x, _
                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Rng.Copy
                    wsBudget.Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(, -5).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(34).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            Else
                'Do something if Rng not found.
            End If

        End With
        Next
End Select
Next ws

            With wsBudget
            Range("D2") = "EUR"
            Range("C2").Select
            Selection.End(xlDown).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
            Selection.FillDown
            End With
```

End Sub

It works although far from an ideal code.  I would appreciate any help on how I can change this [ wsBudget.Range("F1").End(xlDown).Offset(, -5).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(34).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats ] to resize filldown as opposed to having to specify a number of rows (34 in this case). Also any other suggestions of how I can improve the code will be welcome.  Thanks!